# Is "run" in the past participle

Tags: past-participles, bare-infinitives

> That doesn’t mean lying down and becoming fooled, or letting foreign corporations **run** uncontrolled.

I'm not sure about the structure. Is "run" the past  participle or base form (bare infinitive)？
In other words, what's the corresponding finite form of the last part of the sentence:

1. Foreign corporations are run (by somebody) uncontrolled.
2. Foreign corporations run uncontrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure there is *[ "let" + noun + bare infinitive ]*, so the word "run" is the bare infinitive.

This means 2. is a finite form of the last part of that sentence.

Comment: Thanks. "Run"  is seldom used intransitivity when referring to companies or corporations.  The pattern is usually "Somebody runs a company or the company is run by somebody". So I hesitated.